# Yii Query Builder Where LIKE clause

Tags: php, yii, where-clause, sql-like

i am stuck with this code:

```
->select ('t1.id_i, t2.status')
->from ('table1 as t1, table2 as t2')           
->where(array('or', 'id_i'=>$model->id, array('like', 't2.status', '%Beginner%')))
```

here are what i want

```
 WHERE t1.id_i=$model->id AND/OR t2.status LIKE "Beginner" //AND/OR are optional combination
```

i tried a lot combination with no result.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `CDbCommand`'s `where()` method doesn't support using key-value pairs *within* the `$conditions` array as you're doing here: `'id_i'=>$model->id_e`. That binding needs to happen through the `$params` parameter.

That aside, I'd also recommend using a string with value binding instead of the array syntax, as it will make the code easier to read.

Here's the modified code for the call to `where()`:

```
->where('id_i = :id_e OR t2.status LIKE "%Beginner%"', array(':id_e' => $model->id_e))
```

You can see that it's closer to the final SQL, which makes debugging easier.

If you're determined to use the original syntax, try this instead:

```
->where(array('or', 'id_i = :id_e', array('like', 't2.status', '%Beginner%')), array(':id_e' = $model->id_e))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put clause on where() method, on class of CDbCommand, where() method specifies the WHERE part of query, the first argumnet are query condition and second argument are the parameters (name => value) to be bound to the query.

```
->select ('t1.id_i, t2.status')
->from ('table1 as t1, table2 as t2')           
->where('t1.id_i=:id_i OR t2.status LIKE "%:status%"',array(':id_i' => $model->id,':status' => 'Beginner'))
```

more details about CDbCommand where() method [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#where()-detail)

Comment: heya, don't forget to explain what you've changed and why. Don't forget there are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow that could learn a thing or two from your experience, and what's obvious to you might not be to them.